# LM317 output voltage is rising unexpectedly

Tags: lm317

I am using LM317 to get 5.5V out of 12V input

[image]
In my circuit R1 is 220R, R2 is 741R
Expected current is ~700mA.
[link to the data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf)

This of course will produce a lot of heat, so I choose quite a large heat sink.
when working, The heat sink is getting very hot, I will probably have to replace it.

The strange thing however is that after about 2 minutes the output voltage **rise** to 8 to 9 volts.

This is very strange as I expected the overheat protection to protect this from happening.

Removing the heat sink altogether is followed by a drop of the regulated voltage as expected.

So, I am suspecting that the heat sink keeps the LM317 working, but something else is causing the voltage to drift upwards.

I will appreciate any explanation for this phenomena.

Comment: Share your whole circuit?

Comment: The circuit is exactly as shown in the data sheet of the IC

Comment: Do you have any capacitor at the input or the output of a regulator?

Comment: I added link to the datasheet

Comment: yes. 100n at the input and 1u at the output

Comment: Which of the 14 circuits on the 31 page datasheet? Why not help those you are asking to help you by adding the image into your question. That way all the information is in the one place. There is also a CircuitLab schematic editor button on the toolbar if you wish to draw the full schematic with your component values. (Double-click to modify the components.)

Comment: I added the circuit

Comment: Try to increase the output capacitance to 470uF or more.  And the input voltage is DC or from where did you get it?

Comment: The input is DC. Directly from a 5A power suplly

Comment: What exactly is the load which is drawing 700mA?

Comment: I used 8R 10W resistor to emulate the final load and it happened with it.

Comment: What is the TCR of your resistor?

Comment: Your wirewound load resistor may have enough **inductance** to cause instability (i.e. oscillation) . As @G36 says, try 470uF at the regulator output (and leave the 1uF ceramic capacitor in parallel).

Comment: Load. e.g. 300 ppm would change something like 0.2 ohm. hmm... not enough to justify 3V change though

Comment: R1 and R2 is 25PPM/C. for the load resistor, I don't know

Comment: Just shooting in the dark here: 7.4.3 in datasheet: "The load or feedback must consume this minimum current for regulation or the output may be too high." Are you sure there is good contact wit your load resistor?

Comment: Yes. I am measuring the current constantly and it is near 700mA

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities:

1. Faulty connections to R2 or faulty R2 goes high resistance or open when heated.
2. Oscillation due to inductive (wirewound resistor) load and light capacitance
   on the output. Solution- add capacitance.
3. Defective LM317.
4. Incorrect connections to LM317
5. A short somehow across R1.

All these except #2 have to do with construction and component integrity, not design.

Answer (score 0):

1. try R2 with higher wattage. If it is a pot, replace with fixed value resistors. (2 x 1,5k parallel is 750 ohm)
2. increase output cap to 10uF

Comment: Although the question is a couple of years old your answer might help someone if you explain the theory behind your solution and what you think is wrong with the OP's circuit. Welcome to EE.SE.